# Conditional test fails even though the value is the same

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic if condition that is not working.I already tried using `==`
 instead of `===`, tried using `parseInt($value)` with no joy.

Any help please?

```
function displayReward(value, id) {

    var output = '.'+id+"Output";
    if($(value) === 0){      
        alert(value + ' - value is equal to 0');
    }else{
        alert(value + ' - value is greater than 0');
    }
}
```

The markup:

```
<input type="number" name="somename" id="someid" min="0" max="100" step="1" 
    value="0" onChange="displayReward(this.value,this.id);" disabled>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried just comparing the actual `value`? You dont need to wrap your variable in jQuery if that's all it is storing, just use `if (value === 0)` (If you still need to parse it, then `if (parseInt(value) === 0)`

TL;DR: Too much jQuery :)

Comment: Thanks m8 it works! it does not with the "==="  works with "==".

Answer (score 1):

You're using jQuery wrong. This code: `$(value)` attempts to make the `value` variable into a jQuery object, which it is not. In most cases, jQuery objects are only used to manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the jquery selector ( $(value) ) there. Try

```
 if( value == 0){     
    alert(value + ' - value is equal to 0');
 }else{
    alert(value + ' - value is greater than 0');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

to provide a slightly more specific answer on parsing data, I've run into issues with numbers turning into strings a few times.  the === operator compares not only the value of an object, but the type of data as well.  so while (string)`"0"==0`(number) will equate to true, `"0"===0` will equate false.  in order to get data to consistently stick, I run most things through `parseInt()` before evaluating them, or stick with ==.  Also, as stated prior, jQuery isn't used in that fashion.

If you care to read more:
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons)

(this would be a comment, but I lack the rep to comment)